# Is the second `^` in this alternative string redundant?

Tags: regex, syntax, parentheses

In the chapter 1 of `Introducing regular expression`, I see a regex like this:

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

[image]

I'm a little confused with it because the second `^` looks redundant to me. The `|` separates two alternatives `\(\d{3}\)` or `^\d{3}[.-]?` within the parenthesis, and there is aleady a `^` outside the parenthesis, which I understand as to match the start of a line, so I think the second `^` in `^\d{3}[.-]?` is not necessary to match the line begining.  Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend **not** validating phone numbers. There are just too many aspects to consider. For instance, what if someone needs to give you an international number? As an ex-pat, I've had so much trouble with American companies not being able to get their head around the idea that there's a whole world outside North America... :-)

Comment: In what book or reference do you see this ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: fully agreed. And don't even get me started on zip codes.

Comment: `<rant>` Since it's an "introduction". It might intentionally been added to make clear that regex can be "difficult" or "complex" in some situations `</rant>`

Comment: Well-asked question, nice to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look redundant, but there is one possible explanation for it that would be valid (albeit non-sensical given the context).

You've only included the regex pattern in the question; what you haven't shown us is whether any modifiers are being used.

If you use the `m` modifier to switch the regex parser into multi-line mode, then the `^` and `$` anchors change their meaning so that they match the start and end **of a line**, as well as of the entire string.

Therefore, if your expression was using the `m` modifier, the additional `^` would tell it to look for an extra line-feed in that particular instance. So it would have an effect on the expression.

But ultimately, looking at what the expression you quoted actually does, I doubt that this is what is intended; it does look as if it's basically a mistake, as you assume.

Comment: Nice catch, though, on the `m`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks redundant to me as well. The first anchor is sufficient.

Here's how I believe that breaks down into parts:

```
^
(
    \(\d{3}\)
    |
    ^\d{3}[.-]?
)?
\d{3}
[.-]?
\d{4}
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's redundant and useless there. well, it doesn't crash ;)

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_DSXdNu1WwUtNN0t)

The `^` marks the string/line start and doesn't create any result and also the pointer internally isn't moved, so the expressions `^`, `^^` or `^^^^^^^` are all equal.